# The integral of some function of $[x]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, riemann-integration

I am trying to take the following integral which sounds easy but I really got confused and need help.

> $f: [0,2]\to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable. Show that  $$\int_0^2(x-1)f[(x-1)^2]dx=0.$$

For me the answer is $$\int_0^1f[u]du=  f(0)!!$$

which is not necessarily zero. I appreciate any suggestion.

P.S. By $[x]$ the greatest integer less than $x$.

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{2}(x-1)f((x-1)^2)\,dx = \int_{-1}^{1}x f(x^2)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}(x-x) f(x^2)\,dx = 0.$$

Comment: Why do you use angle brackets everywhere ? $f[u]$ is unusual.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a function of the variable [x], which is the greatest integer less than x?

Comment: Shouldn't it be integratable for $f:[-1,0]$ too since that is what you need for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is symmetric through $x=1.$
Set $t=x-1,$ then
$$\int_0^2(x-1)f([x-1]^2)dx=\int_{-1}^1tf([t]^2)dt=f(0)\cdot \int_{-1}^1t\,dt=0$$

Answer (score 1):

I am getting:
$$\int_0^{1^-}(x-1)f(0)dx+\int_{1}^{2^-}(x-1)f(0)dx$$
Which , I think would evaluate to zero

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^2(x-1)f[(x-1)^2]dx = \int_0^1(x-1)f(0)\ dx + \int_1^2(x-1)f([x-1]^2)\ dx$$

Using $u = x-1$ in the second integral,
$$ = \int_0^1(x-1)f(0)\ dx + \int_0^1uf(0)\ du$$
$$ = 2\int_0^1xf(0)\ dx - \int_0^1f(0)dx$$
$$ = f(0)\left.\left(x^2 - x\right)\right|_0^1$$
$$ = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\lfloor (x-1)^2\rfloor=0$ on the open interval $(0,2)$ we have

\begin{eqnarray} \int_0^2(x-1)f\left(\lfloor(x-1)^2\rfloor\right) dx&=&\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_\epsilon^{2-\epsilon}(x-1)f(0)\,dx\\\
&=&f(0)\cdot\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}\bigg|_\epsilon^{2-\epsilon}\\\
&=&f(0)\cdot0\\\
&=&0\end{eqnarray}